# Помогите с пунктуацией. Где ставить точку а где запятные

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Critter(object):
    """Виртуальный питомец"""
    def __init__(self.name):
        print("Появилась на свет новая зверюшка")
        self.name = name 
    def __str__ (self):
        rep = "Объект класса Critter\n"
        rep += "Имя:" + self.name + "\n"
        return rep
    def talk(self):
        print("Привет. Меня зовут" , self.name "\n")
# Basic part
crit1 = Critter(Бобик)
crit1.talk()
crit2 = Critter(Мурзик)
crit2.talk()
print("Вывод объекта crit1 на экран")
print(crit1)
print("Непосредственный доступ к атрибуту crit1.name")
print(crit1.name)
input("\nЖмякни Enter")
```

Answer (score 1):

Строка

```
print("Привет. Меня зовут" , self.name "\n")
```

В ней не хватает знака **+**, должно быть так:

```
print("Привет. Меня зовут", self.name + "\n")
```

Строку

```
def __init__(self.name):
```

заменить на:

```
def __init__(self, name):
```

И имена зверей необходимо заключать в кавычки:

```
crit1 = Critter("Бобик")
crit2 = Critter("Мурзик")
```

Подробнее об объектах класса: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: Тогда уж лучше форматирование использовать: `print("Привет. Меня зовут {}\n".format(self.name))`. Для 3.6 питона: `print(f"Привет. Меня зовут {self.name}\n")`